# How to implement erase method in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, erase, doubly-linked-list

I have to write a doubly linked list, I am trying to implement the `erase(Type obj)` method which takes an argument obj and traverses through the list and deletes every node which has the element obj.

The problem I am facing is, I am iterating through the linked list from front and when I find the node which has the obj element, I change the next/previous pointers of the the nodes before and after the node with obj element. However I am not DELETING the node with obj itself, as far as I know c++ has no garbage collection so the node which had obj is still somewhere hanging in the air. How do I delete that?

My erase()

```
template <typename Type>
int Double_list<Type>::erase( Type const &obj ) {
if (empty()){
    return 0;
}
if (size() == 1 && head()->retrieve() == obj){
    list_head = nullptr;
    list_tail = nullptr;
    list_size--;
    return 1;
}

//Counter to hold the number of items deleted
int count = 0;
    //Iterating through the linked list
for (Double_node<Type> *ptr = head(); ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->next()){
    if (ptr->retrieve() == obj){
        ptr->previous_node->next_node = ptr->next();
        ptr->next()->previous_node = ptr->previous();
        count++;
        // delete ptr; // This stops me from iterating through the for loop
        list_size--;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

Comment: After you've adjusted your pointers, use the `delete` keyword to actually delete the object (free it's memory).

Comment: @ooga Incase I do `delete ptr` after changing the pointers of the nodes before and after the obj node then I cannot traverse through the linked list anymore. Since after deletion I cannot access ptr->next()

Comment: First you set the pointers of the previous and next nodes to its new values and **then** you `delete` the removed node... which is the problem?

Comment: But you would've already copied ptr->next() to the next pointer of the previous node! Actually, you'd just make a copy of it and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you traversing your list, you are doing it using pointer to nodes which is of type `Double_node<Type> *`, which means that it was allocated somewhere and could be deleted with simple `delete ptr`, but since you are using it also to get next element in list you have to be careful and remember it prematurely, so it should be something like:

```
Double_node<Type> *ptr_next = 0;
for (Double_node<Type> *ptr = head(); ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr_next) {
     ptr_next = ptr->next ();
     if (ptr->retrieve() == obj){
     if (ptr->previous_node)
       ptr->previous_node->next_node = ptr->next();

     ptr->next()->previous_node = ptr->previous();
     count++;
     list_size--;
     delete ptr;
    }
```

I believe that should do the trick.

Comment: This: `ptr->previous_node->next_node` will invoke **undefined behavior** if the node being sought turned out to be the head node, in which case `ptr->previous_node` is `NULL`.

Comment: @Predelnik This still has the same problem as my problem. You can delete the pointer `delete ptr` but then you are unable to go to the next node since you are using those pointers to traverse through the for loop

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal You see I do `ptr_next=ptr->next()` to remember whichever node should be processed on the next loop iteration no matter what will happen to `ptr` itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax when deleting pointers and objects called delete.
example code:

```
obj *temp = getCurrentNode();
//set pointers in nodes to the correct places
delete temp; //This releases all of the memory used in the object back to the OS
temp = NULL;//good practice to set this to null, since it points to non-allocated memory
//but exiting the function will make the pointer 'temp' useless, anyway.
```

Comment: as mentioned in my second comment Incase I do delete ptr after changing the pointers of the nodes before and after the obj node then I cannot traverse through the linked list anymore. Since after deletion I cannot access ptr->next()

Comment: You save the memory address in a temporary pointer, as stated above, fix the links to ignore the part you are deleting, and delete it using the temporary pointer.  This takes care of your problem of being unable to access the object after you have changed the links, and also allows you to release the object's space in memory back to the OS